# how can I send input straight to textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, textarea

I am using

```
https://github.com/Rovak/InlineAttachment
```

I currently have it all setup so I can drag and drop images to my textarea and they upload straight to imgur, from following this tutorial:

```
http://wilfreddenton.com/posts/drag-and-drop-photo-uploads-to-imgur
```

what I'm trying to do is add an input so if the user doesnt want to drag and drop, they can simply browse their pc and upload files, and have them go straight into the textarea upon selection.  (just how github comments work)

I just cant seem to get the input to insert into the textarea.

Here's a live example: http://codepen.io/DrCustUmz/pen/KzZOeP

or if your logged into github you can see the end goal what im trying to do: https://github.com/wilfreddenton/dynamic-scss/issues/new

dont actually submit but click "selecting them" below the textarea, pic a few images, and watch the textarea after you click open.

the input selection is not working in this example.  How can I get it so I open the choose files, select a few images, then when I select "open" on the browse my pc popup, they are directly inserted into the textarea, just like i drag and dropped them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the writting work is done in background so I had to rewrite the writting to textarea. Sorry I mostly use pure javascript so I didn't use any fancy jquery features.

This is where the magic happens. The upload can handle only one file at a time so I had to use loop for all of them. I recommend you take a look at the whole code.

```
document.getElementById("inputFile").addEventListener("change", function() {
  var object = this;
  var editor = document.getElementById("editor");
  for(var i=0;i<this.files.length;i++) {
    editor.value += "uploading...";
    uploadHandler.customUploadHandler(this.files[i], function(result) { 
      editor.value = editor.value.replace("uploading...",result.filename);
    });
  }
});
```

[Whole code on CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MyrNLy)

Comment: with the result.filename how can I rap that in [IMG] tags and add a break between each one?

Comment: just replace the result.filename with "\n[IMG]" + result.filename + "[IMG]\n".

Comment: this is perfect =) thank you, the IMG tag is throwing an error though is this correct?
editor.value = editor.value.replace("uploading...",\n[IMG]" + result.filename + "[/IMG]\n);

Comment: you're missing " before the \n[IMG] and after the [/IMG]\n  remember they are still strings.

Comment: yeah i figured it out after I asked lol  Thank you so much!

editor.value = editor.value.replace("uploading...","\n[IMG]" + result.filename + "[/IMG]\n");

Answer (score 1):

You can simply attach the eventListener upon file is selected via choose files option. You just have to trigger the upload in callback. Assume that you've given id of the input type file as "fileUpload"

```
document.getElementById('fileUpload').addEventListener('change', function () {
                console.log(this.files);
                /*trigger the upload here, like you're doing in drag and drop*/
            });
```